# angular $http is returning status 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular 1.0.7

Here is my HTML:

```
<section id="mcslsearch" ng-controller="McslSearchCtrl">
        <div id="search_wrapper">
            <form role="search" id="search_form" ng-submit "performSearch()">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search For A Style Of Music" ng-model="search" value="" name="search" id="search_text">
                <button class="icon" id="search"></button>
                <div class="icon" id="search_hover"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
</section>
```

and my js code:

```
McslApp.controller('McslSearchCtrl', function McslSearchCtrl($scope, $http) {

$scope.search = '';

$scope.performSearch = function () {

    var search = $scope.search,
        url = "a_http://blabla_that_returns_JSON",

        $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
            success(function(data, status) {
                alert("good");
            }).
            error(function(data, status) {
                alert("bad status = "+status);
            });
};
});
```

McslApp is the app that englobes everything (in the  tag).

Does someone see what the problem is here? I tried the shortcut version as well, not better. Alerts "bad status = 0". Is that the fact that I use ng-submit?

This seems so similar to http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#methods_get to me... any suggestions welcome! I'm stuck with that for a good hour now....

**EDIT:**

So apparently the form bit is not what I want, so I tried this in HTML instead:

```
<section id="mcslsearch" ng-controller="McslSearchCtrl">
                    <div id="search_wrapper">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search For A Style Of Music" ng-model="search" value="" name="search" id="search_text">
                        <button ng-click="performSearch()" class="icon" id="search"></button>
                        <div class="icon" id="search_hover"></div>
                    </div>
    </section>
```

with an ng-click but same problem. Calls the JS code but returns status 0 =(

Comment: create a plnkr/fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You are not cancelling the form submission. The status zero is when the page is reloading because of the form submission.

Comment: Same issue with ng-clik instead of form unfortunately.

Comment: You need to cancel the action. return false or preventDefault